# a double free error stemming from set::erase

Tags: c++11, iterator, set

I keep getting the runtime error `double free or corruption (!prev)`. I've spent a while trying things out, and I think I can come up with smaller reproducible example.

This code produces a similar "double free" error. What's going on here? I thought `set::erase` increments the iterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::set<int> tmp = {1,2,3};
    for(auto num = tmp.begin(); num != tmp.end(); ) {
        if(true) {
            std::cout << "removing...\n";
            tmp.erase(num);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought set::erase increments the iterator.

It does not increment the iterator. It returns the next iterator. After erasing, the iterator `num` is invalidated. The valid code looks like below.

```
for(auto num = tmp.begin(); num != tmp.end(); ) {
    if(true) {
        std::cout << "removing...\n";
        num = tmp.erase(num);
    }
}
```